# JTree rendering some non-leaf nodes as leaves with custom renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a custom renderer for a file system that renders different JTree nodes based on whether they are files, directories, etc.  It works for all but a few directories.  For those directories, it renders the icons for the nodes as leaf nodes even though they are directories.

This is the code for the custom renderer:

```
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
                                                  boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        Component treeCellRendererComponent = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        tree.putClientProperty("Tree.paintLines", Boolean.TRUE);

        if (value instanceof FileNode)
        {
            FileNode fileNode = (FileNode) value;
            if (fileNode.isRoot()) { setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon")); }
            else if (fileNode.isDrive()) { setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.hardDriveIcon")); }
            else if (fileNode.getAllowsChildren() && fileNode.getFile().isHidden())
            {
                setIcon(MyIcons.folderHiddenIcon());
            }
            else if (fileNode.getAllowsChildren())
            {
                TreePath treePath = Utilities.getTreePath(fileNode);
                if (tree.isExpanded(treePath)) { setOpenIcon(MyIcons.folderOpenIcon()); }
                else { setClosedIcon(MyIcons.folderClosedIcon()); }
            }
            else { setLeafIcon(MyIcons.fileIcon()); }
        }

        return treeCellRendererComponent;
    }
}
```

This is the custom code for getAllowsChildren()

```
@Override
public boolean getAllowsChildren()
{
    if (getFile() != null) return getFile().isDirectory() || isDrive;
    else return super.getAllowsChildren();
}
```

`FileNode` overrides `DefaultMutableTreeNode`

There are a couple of directories on my Windows 10 system that still render like leaf nodes, such as a directory called "PerfLogs" -- I verified with breakpoints that the code knows PerfLogs is a non-hiddren directory (although it is empty).

Can someone explain please why this directory still renders as a leaf node?

(PS -- I am not worried about the two hard-coded UI icons for root and drive, I will update those later with custom icons)

Thanks!!!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Comment: Java has issues with Windows symbolic links (or what ever Windows calls them), this "might" be an issue.  You'd generally be better off using the NIO2 Paths/Files API which provides you additional functionality to determine if they are linked or not - even if it doesn't solve the immediate problem, it may prevent others in the future